# Swing: Properties button in the standard printing dialog has no effect (Java 8)

Tags: java, swing, printing, awt

The code below shows the standard AWT/Swing printing dialog. All works fine, but in the dialog clicking on the button "Properties" calls no printer properties dialog.

```
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.ServiceUI;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PrintTryout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PrintTryout()::startUp);
    }

    private void startUp() {
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
                DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG, null);
        PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        if (services.length > 0) {
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                    .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
            ServiceUI.printDialog(gc, 50, 50,
                    services, services[0],
                    SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE,
                    attributes);
        }
    }

    private void startUp2() {
        PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        pj.printDialog();
    }
}
```

If I change the invoked method to `startUp2`, I get another printing dialog, that also has the "Properties" button. And this button works correct: I get printer setup dialog. Is it a Java Bug or do I something wrong? Or probably it works correct for somebody (I got this bug from a customer)?

Comment: I suspect that by specifying the DocFlavor as an image, you're "forcing" the printer attribute of the page size.   I've always used startUp2, so I'm not familiar with the code in startUp.

Comment: I have this problem as well, and found this bug that is probably related:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8246742